# Q.all() not returning array of resolved values

Tags: javascript, promise, q

I have a somewhat complicated scenario and I'm not quite understanding why my call to `Q.all` is not returning an array of resolved promises. It is a mix of jQuery `$.ajax` calls and `Q.` calls. Here is the setup:

```
var saveThing1 = function(){
  return $.ajax({...});
}
var saveThing2 = function(){
  return $ajax({...});
}
var deleteThing2 = function(){
  return $.ajax({...});
}

saveThing1.then(function(){
  var promiseArr = [saveThing2(), saveThing2(), deleteThing2()];
  return Q.all(promiseArr);
}).then(function(response){
  var result1 = response[0];
  var result2 = response[1];
  var result3 = response[2];
});
```

[From the Q docs](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promiseall):

> **promise.all()**
>
> Returns a promise that is fulfilled with an array containing the
>   fulfillment value of each promise, or is rejected with the same
>   rejection reason as the first promise to be rejected.

The value of `response` in this case ends up being the single Promise instead of the array of promise values. This is what the Chrome Dev Tools produces when I pause the debugger and log what the `response` value is:

```
Promise {}
  inspect:()
  promiseDispatch:(resolve, op, operands)
  valueOf:()
```

Another thing that I'm still scratching my head at is that the `.then` gets hit while the network requests are still pending, which means the promises in the array passed to `Q.all` should also be pending...

Comment: You need to call your functions (e.g. `saveThing1().then`) for a promise to be returned

Comment: `saveThing1.then()` should be `saveThing1().then()`.

Comment: jQuery ajax promises are a screwy beast.  They don't resolve to a single value themselves (which is completely non-standard) which can really mess things up sometimes.

Comment: What jfriend said. Use `Q(saveThing1()).then(…)`

Comment: Thanks guys. I guess I won't trust jQuery 2.x promises!

Answer (score 2):

`.all` will not do anything with a function, it requires a Promise (or a Promise-like object). You are currently passing a function, not a promise. In order for this to work, all of your functions need to be called:

```
var saveThing1 = function(){
  return $.ajax({...});
}
var saveThing2 = function(){
  return $ajax({...});
}
var deleteThing2 = function(){
  return $.ajax({...});
}

saveThing1().then(function(){
  // populate the array with returned promises, not functions that return promises
  var promiseArr = [saveThing2(), saveThing2(), deleteThing2()];
  return Q.all(promiseArr);
}).then(function(response){
  var result1 = response[0];
  var result2 = response[1];
  var result3 = response[2];
});
```

Comment: Sorry, they are being called in my code. I generalized it on here (obviously) and cut some of the bloat/unrelated things out. I've updated the example code.